# 2 dimension java array into javascript function

Tags: gwt

How to pass 2 dimension java array into javascript function? Array of mixed type.

```
String[][] str={
            {"Year", "Austria", "Bulgaria", "Denmark", "Greece"},
            {"2003",  "1336060",    "400361",    "1001582",   "997974"},
            {"2004",  "1538156",    "366849",    "1119450",   "941795"},
            {"2005",  "1576579",    "440514",    "993360",    "930593"},
                    {"2006",  "1600652",    "434552",    "1004163",   "897127"},
                    {"2007",  "1968113",    "393032",    "979198",    "1080887"},
                    {"2008",  "1901067",    "517206",    "916965",    "1056036"}


private native void createChart(String[][] str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have posted this in a commet but I don't think its really readable there. In GWT there is thie JsArrayMixed which you can pass to the JSNI. As an example here is the following code:

```
JsArrayMixed bigArray= JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast();
for(int i=1;i<yourNumberOfRows;i++) { 
    JsArrayMixed row= JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast(); 
    for(int j=0;j<yourDataRowCount;j++) { 
        row.push(str[i][j]); 
    } 
    bigArray.push(row); 
}
```

Hope this helps,
Ovi